# Order By month and year in sql with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and the select statement is:

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
```

this shows the sum total for every month 
But I need to order the result by month and year coz my result shown like:

```
April 2013 
February 2013 
January 2013 
June 2013 
March 2013 
May 2013
```

What is the solution in such a case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, MONTH(OrderDate), YEAR(OrderDate)
order by Year(orderDate),month(OrderDate)
```

Note you need to add any fields you are ordering by to the group by clause

Answer (score 8):

Just add

```
Order by max(OrderDate)
```

at the end.

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year,     SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
Order by max(OrderDate)
```

Now about how it works:

If you order by month , year separately, it will go in ascending order of month in alphabetical order (April before January). If you order by order date id will be ordered based on a date value which is of course ordered by month/year.

Comment: let me know if it serves your purpose..!!

Comment: This won't work as the orderby field needs to be in the group by clause

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `order by` clause at the end

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate) 
ORDER BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
```

or

you can do like this

```
SELECT     CASE { fn MONTH(OrderDate) } 
            when 0 then 'JAN'
            when 1 then 'FEB'
            when 2 then 'MAR'
            when 3 then 'APR'
            when 4 then 'MAY'
            when 5 then 'JUN'
            when 6 then 'JUL'
            when 7 then 'AUG'
            when 8 then 'SEP'
            when 9 then 'OCT'
            when 10 then 'NOV'
            when 11 then 'DEC'
           END
      AS MonthName, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
    FROM         [Order]
    WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
    GROUP BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate) 
    ORDER BY { fn MONTH(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate)
```

Comment: thanks but Sorry I Tried this and still give the same result April then February the January  .....

Comment: thank you in this case fn MONTH(OrderDate) not in the group by  so i have but it instead of fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) , and that's work good , but i need to show the month name not number ..

Comment: @bruce what happened to you, are you really confuse to accept any answer ? ? :D

Comment: hehe sorry am new at the website , i think that may i can accept more than one answer :))) thanks  @jWeavers

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order as Jan, Feb, March use

```
SELECT 
  month(OrderDate) MonthName, 
  year(OrderDate) Year, 
  sum(TotalValue) Profits
FROM         
  [Order]
WHERE     
  month(OrderDate) = @year
ORDER BY 
  year(OrderDate), 
  month(OrderDate)
GROUP BY 
  year(OrderDate),
  month(OrderDate)
```

Comment: i tried this and i get this error:Column "Order.OrderDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Ryan you don't need to put it in the `SELECT` part, you need to put any order by clauses into the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Use Following query it will work for you.

```
SELECT     { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, datepart(MM,OrderDate)                     AS Month, YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM         [Order]
WHERE     (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, YEAR(OrderDate),     datepart(MM,**OrderDate**) 
ORDER BY datepart(MM,**OrderDate**)
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain a little your answer so the OP can understand your insight? Pretty please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works perfectly. Note that you already entering a year value. So you don't need to order or group Year since you can only choose one Year at a time. So the extra code is not needed.

```
SELECT { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) } AS MonthName, SUM(TotalValue) AS Profits
FROM [Order]
WHERE (YEAR(OrderDate) = @year)
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(OrderDate) }, DATEPART(M, OrderDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(M, OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
cast(year(appointmentdate) as char(4))+''+ 
case when len(cast(month(appointmentdate)as char(2)))=1 
then '0'+cast(  month(appointmentdate) as char(2) ) else cast(month(appointmentdate) as char(2))end  as apporder
from timeslots  
group by appointmentdate
order by appOrder
```