# How to do an "Order By" by the month and year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

Code:

```
SELECT

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Due_Date,101) AS Due_Date,
COST_PER_ACRES,
CASE WHEN Due_Amount IS NOT NULL AND Lease_Amount IS NOT NULL THEN '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(Due_Amount - Lease_Amount AS MONEY),1)
WHEN Due_Amount IS NULL THEN '$0.00' ELSE '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(Due_Amount AS MONEY),1) END AS RENTAL_AMOUNT_DUE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CHECK_DATE,101) AS Check_Date

FROM tblpayments PH 
LEFT JOIN tblcheck CD
    ON PH.ID = CD.lease_obligation_ID

WHERE PH.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID = 1657 AND PH.LEASE_ID = 76

ORDER BY YEAR(Due_Date)
```

I want to know how can I get the following output:

[image]

My current output:

[image]

Comment: `ORDER BY MONTH(Due_Date),YEAR(Due_Date)`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271316/order-by-month-and-year-in-sql-with-sum

Answer (score 2):

You would just add `month()` to the `order by`.  So I think you want:

```
ORDER BY MONTH(ph.Due_Date), YEAR(ph.Due_Date)
```

(I don't know where the column comes from.  I'm just guessing `ph`.)

In your case, you can also do:

```
ORDER BY Due_Date
```

The `Due_Date` is interpreted based on the column alias.  It appears to be what you want to order by.

Note:  renaming a column to the same as an existing column can cause confusion in the `ORDER BY`.