# SQL Server Query : Month sort

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sort month But this is the result.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM ClientsDataAging ORDER BY Month ASC
```

Result

[image]

It seems it was sorted Alphabetically.

I want the result that sorts monthly like Jan, Feb, March etc. etc.

I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271676/9651031
but It seems it is differ from my case so, any help will be appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have your months stored as string data, the output you currently see is correct, because those dates are sorting as text, and not dates.  One option would be to use `CONVERT` with format mask 107:

```
SELECT Month
FROM ClientsDataAging
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(Month, 1, 3) + ' 01 18');
```

[image]

The trick here is that, for example, for the month 'January', we build the string `'Jan 01 18'`.  This is the format of `'Mon dd, yy'` which `CONVERT` expects for mask 107.  So we convert your text month into a bona fide date on the first of that month.  I arbitrarily use `2018` as the year, but this should not matter, since you never mentioned any year data.

Here is a demo showing that all the text months convert properly.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the response but it says Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
why is it?

Comment: I have no idea.  My code is working in the demo, and I think it would also run on SSMS.  You must be doing something with your data which I can't see.

Comment: @Cremlic If you have other issues, drop a comment, otherwise maybe open a new question if you have some other big requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It will require to convert name to month number in ORDER BY.
something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM ClientsDataAging ORDER BY 
DATEPART(MM,Month + ' 01 2018')   ASC
```

(.. i have not tested it because posting this from phone)

Edit for *ORDER BY items must appear in..*:

```
;with t as 
(select distinct [Month], DATEPART(MM, [Month] + ' 01 2018') MonthNum from ClientsDataAging)
select [Month] From t ORDER BY MonthNum ASC
```

...You should have removed `DISTINCT` if you don't need it as done in accepted answer.

Comment: uhggg my hunch is correct I've seen something like convert the string to month number etc. etc., shoot I'd better try you suggestion Thanks

Comment: Hi it says ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @Cremlic, if you don't need DISTINCT as done in accepted answer of Tim Biegeleisen, you should mention in original post. It makes much difference with and without DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month FROM ClientsDataAging ORDER BY MONTH('01-' + [Month] + '-2018') ASC
```

Try above script.